# Getting "Add to Home Screen" to ignore the jQuery Mobile sub-page

Tags: jquery-mobile

When someone adds my web app to their home screen whilst they are, for example, on the "#settings" page, the settings page is getting loaded when they click on the icon..

Is there a way of getting the icon to always start the home page regardless from which page the user added it?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure there is, because `add-to-homescreen` is like a adding a bookmark to a page specified and there is no way to modify the URL being bookmarked (at least none I know...)

What you could do is a re-direct client/server side.

For example I'm checking on pages, if the user is logged in or not and if not I redirect to the login page. So the bookmark can be added to ...say the settings page, but the user will always be redirected to login, which should work in your case, too.

Comment: Oh yeah, something like sessionStorage or a cookie could tell me whether they've just opened the app and then I can redirect - I'll try it out!